# Can I use SAML with another authentication provider in a single web application

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml

I have a Spring application already using Spring security with a local store of users. I want to also allow an IDP login via SAML assertion, but only for people who already have an account with my application.

1) Can I configure spring security to optionally use SAML authentication provider OR an LDAP authentication provider? 2) When someone authenticates via SAML, can I populate their session principle with information from the local user store? 3) Finally, can I do this through Spring configuration, or do I need to do it programmatically?

Answer (score 4):

1. Yes, you can freely combine different authentication methods together with SAML in a single application
2. Yes
3. You will need to write your own implementation of `SAMLUserDetailsService` interface which will do the population

Comment: but how can I implement the `SAMLUserDetailsService` so that it takes the user to an idp web application like okta for authentication.